# Помогите понять, в чем ошибка

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

```
                $connect->query('INSERT INTO fw_check (`tgID`, 
                                                    `number`,
                                                    `sity`,
                                                    `region`,
                                                    `flowers`,
                                                    `count`,
                                                    `promocode`,
                                                    `summ`,
                                                    `payment_method`,
                                                    `purse`,
                                                    `status`) VALUES ("'.$id.', 
                                                                        "'.$number.'",
                                                                        "'.$UsersInfo[0]['sity'].'",
                                                                        "'.$UsersInfo[0]['region'].'",
                                                                        "'.$UsersInfo[0]['flowers'].'",
                                                                        "'.$UsersInfo[0]['count'].'",
                                                                        "'.$UsersInfo[0]['promocode'].'",
                                                                        "'.$summ.'",
                                                                        "'.$payment.'",
                                                                        "'.$purse.'",
                                                                        "0")');
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка? Исключение выкидывает? Не вставляет?

Comment: Не вставляет. Пробовал $connect->query('INSERT INTO fw_check (`tgID`) VALUES ("0")');, работает, а если всё вместе, нет.

Comment: Выведите текст запроса в консоль. Потом скопируйте в MySQL Workbench и смотрите, что за ошибку выдает.

Comment: Узнав ее, будем смотреть, что можно сделать

Answer (score -1):

```
VALUES ("'.$id.',
```

Скобку не написал. Ниже правильный вариант.

```
VALUES ("'.$id.'",
```